# ASP.NET C# - Image path not saving in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, path

I am uploading images to the database and storing the name and path in the database but the actual image is being stored in a folder. I have sucessfully stored them in the folder but it is not saving the information about the image to the databse.

Any help is much appreciated. Below is my code behind:

```
    private void StartUpLoad()
    {

        //get the file name of the posted image
        string imgName = FileUpload1.FileName.ToString();

        //sets the image path
        string imgPath = "images/" + imgName;

        //then save it to the Folder
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(imgPath));

        //get the size in bytes that
        int imgSize = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;

        //validates the posted file before saving
        if (FileUpload1.PostedFile != null && FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName != "")
        {
            if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength > 5120) // 5120 KB means 5MB
            {
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "Alert", "alert('File is too big')", true);
            }

            else
            {
                //save the file
                //Call the method to execute Insertion of data to the Database
                ExecuteInsert(imgName, imgSize, imgPath);
                Response.Write("Save Successfully!");
            }
        }
    }

    private string GetConnectionString()
    {
        //sets the connection string from your web config file. "DBConnection" is the name of your Connection String
        return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    }

    private void ExecuteInsert(string name, int size, string path)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
        string sql = "INSERT INTO ImageInfo (ImageName, ImageSize, ImagePath) VALUES "
                    + " (@ImgName,@ImgSize,@ImgPath)";
        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[3];

            param[0] = new SqlParameter("@ImgName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
            param[1] = new SqlParameter("@ImgSize", SqlDbType.BigInt, 9999);
            param[2] = new SqlParameter("@ImgPath", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);

            param[0].Value = name;
            param[1].Value = size;
            param[2].Value = path;

            for (int i = 0; i < param.Length; i++)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param[i]);
            }

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
        {
            string msg = "Insert Error:";
            msg += ex.Message;       
        }

        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StartUpLoad();
    }
```

Below is my asp.net code

```
<div>
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Save" onclick="Button1_Click" />
</div>
```

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint in your catch and read the exceptions, if there are any?

Answer (score 0):

Your image path and name are only set to allow 50 characters and your image path plus name is most likely longer than that. Check the size of those values in the debug. If they are longer then 50 characters then the database is rejecting the insert.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you debug your code, copy/paste your insert command into the database manager and see if it raises an exception.